# Send email when new record is inserted in database

Tags: laravel, api, email

I am creating an api for student management system in laravel. I want to send email to the students when faculty enters their record in the database saying that their admission is successful. How can I do that?

Comment: you should read about events and listeners and then trigger an event after insertion in database. you can send emails through events.

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? If yes, then please share or else try using Laravel markdown mail feature to do this functionality. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail Refer this link.

Answer (score 1):

Notifications!

In the method where you insert the record, you want to **notify** some users.
Final result would look like this:

```
use App\Notifications\StudentAdmitted;
...
public function doSomething(Request $request, Student $student) 
{
    $student->admitted = true;
    $student->notify(new StudentAdmitted);

}
```

**Create the notification**

```
php artisan make:notification StudentAdmitted
```

**Edit it**

You want to modify the toMail method

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Congratulations!')
                ->line('you have been accepted')
                ->action('View', url('/url/to/page'))
                ->line('something here');
}
```

Moreover, the Student or User model should use the Notifiable trait.

```
...
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    ....
```